# Appium - How to solve [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 28 ms - 83

Tags: appium

I install appium then I want to run apk in appium. When I run I get message like this, so I can't run APK:

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.5.3

[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   address: '127.0.0.1'
[Appium]   debugLogSpacing: true
[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '4.4'
[Appium]   automationName: 'Appium'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'AndroidTestDevice'
[Appium]   app: '/Users/andika/Desktop/trash-app.apk'
[Appium] Deprecated server args:
[Appium]   --platform-name => --default-capabilities '{"platformName":"Android"}'
[Appium]   --platform-version => --default-capabilities '{"platformVersion":"4.4"}'
[Appium]   --automation-name => --default-capabilities '{"automationName":"Appium"}'

[Appium]   --device-name => --default-capabilities '{"deviceName":"AndroidTestDevice"}'
[Appium]   --app => --default-capabilities '{"app":"/Users/andika/Desktop/trash-app.apk"}'
[Appium] Default capabilities, which will be added to each request unless overridden by desired capabilities:

[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '4.4'
[Appium]   automationName: 'Appium'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'AndroidTestDevice'
[Appium]   app: '/Users/andika/Desktop/trash-app.apk'

[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []

[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...

[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 28 ms - 83 

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []

[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 12 ms - 83
```

When I do appium doctor, everything is fine.

**UPDATED**
Sorry, this is the error: 
[image: This is the error]

General setting: 
[image]

Comment: In your logs, i cant see the error, can you share the logs as an attachment or the part where you received the error.

Comment: @Keshav sorry, I have uploaded the error

Comment: -can you please share the screenshot of settings as well. also did you tried resolution given in my answer?

Comment: @AndikaKurniawan Can you mention the UDID property in desired capabilities and then try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have mentioned wrong device name as  deviceName: 'AndroidTestDevice'.
Please find your device name using command
"`adb devices`" and use the name in appium gui. also in logs, error details is not displayed, if above resolution does not work, please share the full logs.

Comment: @AndikaKurniawan  - can you please share the screenshot of settings as well. also did you tried resolution given in my answer?

Comment: thank you, now it's solved. But I have to run appium in terminal

Comment: @AndikaKurniawan - Great, Happy to hear that. I think in GUI it was related to some settings.

Comment: Yeah... it's dizzy

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

I start Appium server in terminal **not click running** in Appium app. 
I do Igor Vishnevskiy's answer until I am able to start Appium server...

[How to setup Appium on Mac OS to run automated tests from JAVA classes on Android and iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813589/how-to-setup-appium-on-mac-os-to-run-automated-tests-from-java-classes-on-androi)

Then, if you want to run Android app in Appium. 
I set *server address and port* in general preferences like this : 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fPus.jpg)

Then I set android preference like this : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4klIP.jpg)

Details Info :

1. Set *App Path* to your APK location
2. Run your emulator then set *Launch AVD name* and *Device Name*  by type `adb devices` (**thank you @Keshav**)
3. Set *Platform Name*, *Automation Name* like in picture
4. You can choose any *Platform Version*

Then :

1. Start server in terminal by type `appium &`
2. Click 'search icon' in Appium app to run your apk in Appium