# "Appium &" won't start Appium server in mac

Tags: npm, appium, npm-install, macos-mojave

I have downloaded all the required tools and also able to set up environment variable in the system.
macOS mojave : version 10.14.3

I have install node, appium and wd:

```
brew install node
npm install -g appium
npm install wd
```

when i try yo start appium server using **appium &** I got following error;

> [1] 49460
>
> -bash: appium: command not found
>
> [1]+  Exit 127                appium

Updated:

> None of app opens which is installed using npm command. The app installed using npm shows **command not found error**
>
> It was working fine in macOs Mojave 10.14.2

Logs while using **npm install -g appium**

```
$npm install -g appium
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.0.1: Not Ready For Production
/Users/infotmt/bin/appium -> /Users/infotmt/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js

> appium-chromedriver@4.9.0 install /Users/infotmt/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver
> node install-npm.js

[18:22:48] [Chromedriver Install] Installing Chromedriver version '2.44' for platform 'mac' and architecture '64'
[18:22:48] [Chromedriver Install] Opening temp file to write 'chromedriver_mac64' to...
[18:22:48] [Chromedriver Install] Opened temp file '/var/folders/ng/_2f_j78n1vg4gf8xnxvx9c780000gn/T/2019025-62054-1018qcf.8dtn/chromedriver_mac64.zip'
[18:22:48] [Chromedriver Install] Downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/chromedriver_mac64.zip...
[18:22:52] [Chromedriver Install] Writing binary content to /var/folders/ng/_2f_j78n1vg4gf8xnxvx9c780000gn/T/2019025-62054-1018qcf.8dtn/chromedriver_mac64.zip...
[18:22:52] [Chromedriver Install] Extracting /var/folders/ng/_2f_j78n1vg4gf8xnxvx9c780000gn/T/2019025-62054-1018qcf.8dtn/chromedriver_mac64.zip to /var/folders/ng/_2f_j78n1vg4gf8xnxvx9c780000gn/T/2019025-62054-1018qcf.8dtn/chromedriver_mac64
[18:22:52] [Chromedriver Install] Creating /Users/infotmt/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/mac...
[18:22:52] [Chromedriver Install] Copying unzipped binary, reading from /var/folders/ng/_2f_j78n1vg4gf8xnxvx9c780000gn/T/2019025-62054-1018qcf.8dtn/chromedriver_mac64/chromedriver...
[18:22:52] [Chromedriver Install] Writing to /Users/infotmt/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/mac/chromedriver...
[18:22:52] [Chromedriver Install] /Users/infotmt/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/mac/chromedriver successfully put in place

> appium-selendroid-driver@1.13.2 install /Users/infotmt/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-selendroid-driver
> node ./bin/install.js

[18:22:54] Java version 1.8.0_202 found
[18:22:55] Ensuring /Users/infotmt/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-selendroid-driver/selendroid/download exists
[18:22:55] Downloading Selendroid standalone server version 0.17.0 from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/selendroid/selendroid-standalone/0.17.0/selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar --> /Users/infotmt/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-selendroid-driver/selendroid/download/selendroid-server-7cf7163ac47f1c46eff95b62f78b58c1dabdec534acc6632da3784739f6e9d82.jar
[18:23:07] Writing binary content to /Users/infotmt/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-selendroid-driver/selendroid/download/selendroid-server.jar.tmp
[18:23:07] Selendroid standalone server downloaded
[18:23:07] Determining AndroidManifest location
[18:23:07] Determining server apk location
[18:23:07] Extracting manifest and apk to /Users/infotmt/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-selendroid-driver/selendroid/download
[18:23:07] Copying manifest and apk to /Users/infotmt/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-selendroid-driver/selendroid
[18:23:07] Cleaning up temp files
[18:23:07] Fixing AndroidManifest icon bug

> appium-windows-driver@1.5.1 install /Users/infotmt/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-windows-driver
> node install-npm.js

Not installing WinAppDriver since did not detect a Windows system

> fsevents@2.0.1 install /Users/infotmt/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/fsevents
> [ -f fsevents.node ] || npm run prepare


> heapdump@0.3.12 install /Users/infotmt/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/heapdump
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/addon/src/heapdump.o
In file included from ../src/heapdump.cc:17:
../../nan/nan.h:1064:44: warning: 'ToString' is deprecated: Use maybe version
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      v8::Local<v8::String> string = from->ToString(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent());
                                           ^
/Users/infotmt/.node-gyp/11.7.0/include/node/v8.h:2537:3: note: 'ToString' has
      been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED("Use maybe version",
  ^
/Users/infotmt/.node-gyp/11.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded
      from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
1 warning generated.
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/addon.node
+ appium@1.10.1
added 493 packages from 406 contributors and updated 2 packages in 34.024s
```

Comment: while this link my be the answer of the question 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813589/how-to-setup-appium-on-mac-os-to-run-automated-tests-from-java-classes-on-androi

Comment: that didn't helped me

Comment: give me some time i will let you know

Comment: @akshaypatil i tried to install appium in another mac with the version 10.14.2 and it works fine. While typing **appium** in terminal, it opens appium server.

Comment: hmm that's good and  one more thing, any how does this solution helps you if help then please up-vote otherwise let it be..

Comment: It is not working in my system. My mac os version is 10.14.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that i installed the node/npm in very old version of mac. Then i upgraded the mac version to mojave.
I solve the issue by factory resetting the mac and then updating it to latest version. After that i install node/npm and then appium. It works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is as follows:

#### 1. Do not use Homebrew to install Node.js.

The best way to do this is to use the `nvm` version manager. I had many conflicts with Node.js on MacOS, but `nvm` is a bulletproof solution.

https://yoember.com/nodejs/the-best-way-to-install-node-js/

#### 2. It is also highly recommended to use version managers for

- Ruby https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv
- Python https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv
- Java http://www.jenv.be/

Version managers take over Node/Ruby/Python/Java management from the system and allow you to install parallel versions and keep consistency of modules/packages/gems etc.

#### 3. Then install the following packages:

```
npm install -g appium
npm install -g appium-doctor
```

After that you can check the list of **all** Appium dependencies:

```
appium-doctor --ios
appium-doctor --android
```

Follow the instructions and complete the list.

#### 4. Never install modules/packages/gems... with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to start appium server using desktop client?
https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.10.0

Also did you refer this https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6738?

Comment: Appium desktop is working. The problem was I had installed appium server version in the old mac os and then updated it to mojave. I sloved this problem by clearing mac os to its default, and then update the os. After that i installed the appium sever again and it works

Answer (score 0):

Check your `$PATH` environment variable for existence of `/Users/infotmt/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the desktop version from releases: https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop

Did you try to install `appium-doctor`?

Try running `npm install -g appium-doctor` as kubano tolds you. I'm currently using it in mojave, so feel free to ask me anything

Answer (score 0):

Try installing appium if you installed using brew `brew install appium` it will install the appium server on local under `user`

Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

brew install node
npm install -g appium
npm install wd

If not worked you can write
sudo npm install -g appium